# How can I add a downloadable file to my Github.io page?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have set up my professional website/homepage using `Github Pages`. I know if this was just `HTML` being served up from somewhere, my downloadable file would need to be in the directory of my `.html` file, and then I could reference it in the `.html` file and link it up. However, since this is served by Github through repository, I am unsure on how to do this.

1. Do I put my downloadable file in my repo under version control like the rest of the project?
2. If so, what path do I use in the `.html` file?

Also, I am aware that the `Automatic Page Generator` makes it possible to hardly touch the HTML, but it seems pretty restrictive as far as customizing where links and other content appears on your page...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just link it normally in your html. Commit it to your repository and have users right click to save.

I just tried this on one of my repositories where I put a link to my CSS file.

```
<a href="css/style.css">style.css</a>
```

I was able to right click the link and download the file.
If you wanted to create a download from the root you would do:

```
<a href="file.txt">Download File</a>
```

I'm pushing my repositories manually instead of using the Automatic Page Generator. The steps are pretty straight forward [Creating Project Pages Manually - GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually)

Comment: Don't forget you can add the "download" attribute to the <a> tag. This allows the user to download the file by clicking on it. <a href="/files/ryan_pelletier_resume.docx" download>Download My Resume</a>

Comment: @ryanp102694 I'm fairly sure it should be `download="download"`, though that's only for compatibility reasons (at least in HTML5, the two are exactly equivalent)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes That is probably true, I only tested it in a recent version of Chrome.

Comment: @FundMonica'sLawsuit "The download attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource. The attribute may have a value; the value, if any, specifies the default file name that the author recommends for use in labeling the resource in a local file system. " https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download

Answer (score 0):

Since it is done in GitHub pages. It can also be done like this (in markdown fashion): `[download]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link file.txt %})`. It has the advantage to work locally without pushing the file to the repo.